# How to fix this error “Index exceeds the number of array elements (57)” while using minboundquad function

Tags: matlab, geometry, computational-geometry, bounding-box

Error shown is [Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqZE0.jpg)

```
%x = randn(50,1);
%y = randn(50,1);
points=importdata('points1.txt');
x=points(:,1);
y=points(:,2);
[qx,qy] = minboundquad(x,y);
plot(x,y,'ro',qx,qy,'b-')
```

The function is working for randomly generated points but not working for my [pointset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bK4VnvIJhF29phOckB7NBa6gkLhmIuqV/view). Can someone please help me solve this? This is the function [minboundquad](https://viewer.mathworks.com/?viewer=plain_code&url=https%3A%2F%2Fin.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Fmlc-downloads%2Fdownloads%2Fsubmissions%2F34767%2Fversions%2F3%2Fcontents%2FMinBoundSuite%2Fminboundquad.m&embed=web) in [Matlab](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects)

Or Please lead/help me to find a minimum bounding quadrilateral for a given set of points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying these lines in minboundquad.m from

```
edges = convhull(x,y);
```

to

```
edges = convhull(x,y,'Simplify',true);
```

and

```
if ( A_i < quadarea)
```

to

```
if (( A_i < quadarea)&& all(abs([qxi qyi]) < 1e15))
```

resolves the issue.